# Can Spotify be paused when a Skype call is made, similar to how iTunes does it?

Tags: itunes, music, spotify

When I am listening to music on iTunes, the music is automatically paused when a Skype call is made. I recently switch to Spotify for my music resource. Can I have the same pausing functionality with Spotify, as with iTunes?

Comment: What research did you do so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. Here are two possible solutions:

- **Python**. This has been answered on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779578/how-to-programatically-pause-spotify-when-a-call-comes-in-on-skype) already.
- [**Simplify**](http://mmth.us/simplify/). One of Simplify's features is auto-pausing on Skype calls:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're are using Mac OS (OS X) try this AppleScript I quickly bashed up, (please note I'm not really an OS X developer and my knowledge of AppleScript is, to say the least, 'intermediate')

https://github.com/jhuseinovic/skype-spotify-ctrl

```
(*
This script was developed by John Huseinovic (john@huseinovic.net)
The purpose of the script is to pause any playing track in Spotify when there is a active/incoming call in skype and resume playing after the call is finished.
The script will only monitor if the both Skype and Spotify are running!
*)
set spotify_status to null
set notificationTitle to "Skype-Spotify Controller"
set call_started to false
set music_was_playing to false
repeat
    if application "Skype" is running and application "Spotify" is running then
        tell application "Skype"
            set calls to «event sendskap» given «class cmnd»:"SEARCH ACTIVECALLS", «class scrp»:"AnsweringScript"
            set callID to last word of calls
            if callID is not "CALLS" then

                using terms from application "Spotify"
                    set spotify_status to the player state of application "Spotify" as string
                end using terms from

                set status to «event sendskap» given «class cmnd»:"GET CALL " & callID & " STATUS", «class scrp»:"AnsweringScript"
                set caller to «event sendskap» given «class cmnd»:"GET CALL " & callID & " PARTNER_HANDLE", «class scrp»:"AnsweringScript"
                set call_started to true
                #log "set call_started to " & call_started
                if spotify_status = "playing" then
                    set music_was_playing to true
                    display notification "Active call with " & last word of caller & "! Spotify was " & spotify_status & ", going to pause it." with title notificationTitle
                    tell application "Spotify" to pause
                end if
            else
                #log "call_started is " & call_started
                if call_started is true and music_was_playing is true then
                    display notification "Detected terminated Skype call, resuming Spotify! Enjoy =)" with title notificationTitle
                    tell application "Spotify" to play
                end if
                set call_started to false
            end if
        end tell
        delay 1
    else
        delay 10
    end if

end repeat
```